# Приостановить поток в Qt

Tags: qt, многопоточность, qt5

Вопрос оказался не тривиальным. Метод указанный ниже работал, для однопоточной программы, в многопоточной сделать паузу не удаётся. Подскажите пожалуйста правильный вариант.

```
class Sleep: public QThread {
public:
    static void msleep(int ms)
    {
        QThread::msleep(ms);
    }
};

...
Sleep::msleep(1000);
...
```

Далее примерная архитектура моего приложения:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
...
  TransportMail *tm = new TransportMail();
  TaskThred thredTm;
  tm->moveToThread(&thredTm);
  thredTm.start();
...
}
void TransportMail::sendMail(QString mail)
{
...
sleep(10); // не работает
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `msleep`, которая предложена в вашей программе приостанавливает только поток, в котром она выполняется. Хотите приостанавить всю программу - выполните эту функцию в каждом потоке, который хотите приостанавить. приостанавить конкретный поток можно вызвав `hThread->msleep(10);`.

Comment: Вероятно вы имели в виду что мне сначала нужно получить указатель на свой поток, с этим у меня проблема, пока занимаюсь ёе решением. Функция Sleep::msleep(1000); останавливает всю программу если она однопоточна, иначе ни как не влияет ни на поток в котором запущенна.